# Changing CSS based on service variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I'm new to Angular, but it seems to be the "Angular way" to avoid DOM manipulation whenever possible.  I am not sure if I'm taking the right approach.

I have three buttons on the bottom (next,back, and home).  These get enabled and disabled by way of the actions of other controllers.  For example if a text box is NULL the next button will be disabled until something is entered.  I have the following:

```
    <div ng-controller="nextBackController" class="navbar navbar-app navbar-absolute-bottom">
        <div class="btn-group justified">
          <a href="#/" class="btn btn-navbar btn-icon-only btn-bounded"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-navbar" ng-class="{'btn-disabled' : btnBack}"></i> Back</a>
          <a id="btnHome" ng-click="handleClick()" href="#/" class="btn btn-navbar btn-icon-only btn-bounded" ng-class="{'btn-disabled' : btnHome}"><i class="fa fa-home fa-navbar"></i> Home</a>
          <a href="#/second" class="btn btn-navbar btn-icon-only">Next <i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-navbar" ng-class="{'btn-disabled' : btnNext}"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And now for the JS:

```
app.service("nxtBackClick", function($rootScope, bottomButtonWatcher) {

    this.btn = "";

    this.broadcast = function(btn) {
        //Toggle the Next button as an example
        bottomButtonWatcher.btnNext = ~bottomButtonWatcher.btnNext;

        //set the btn that is clicked
        this.btn = btn;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('bottomBtnClick');
    };
});

app.service("bottomButtonWatcher", function($rootScope) {

    //Set all these to disabled
    this.btnHome = true;
    this.btnNext = false;
    this.btnBack = true;

});
```

And now the controller:

```
//####################### - Next Back Controller ########################
app.controller("nextBackController",
    function($scope, nxtBackClick, bottomButtonWatcher){

        $scope.btnHome = bottomButtonWatcher.btnHome;
        $scope.btnNext = bottomButtonWatcher.btnNext;
        $scope.btnBack = bottomButtonWatcher.btnBack;

        $scope.handleClick = function(btn) {
            nxtBackClick.broadcast(btn);
        };
    }

);
```

Comment: What exactly is your issue - is this code not working? The "Angular Way" doesn't particularly discourage DOM manipulation, but prefers it be done through the use of directives.

Comment: When I update bottomButtonWatcher.btnNext, I don't think that $scope.btnNext is updating as well, thus triggering the CSS change

Answer (score 0):

Having both a class attribute and an ng-class attribute can be problematic. They should both be condensed into a single ng-class attribute. You are already passing an object, so just add another property to it. Setting classes to always be shown is accomplished by setting their property to true.

```
<div ng-controller="nextBackController" class="navbar navbar-app navbar-absolute-bottom">
    <div class="btn-group justified">
      <a href="#/" class="btn btn-navbar btn-icon-only btn-bounded">
         <i ng-class="{'fa fa-arrow-left fa-navbar': true, 'btn-disabled' : btnBack}"></i>      
         Back
      </a>
      <a id="btnHome" ng-click="handleClick()" href="#/" ng-class="{'btn btn-navbar btn-icon-only btn-bounded':true, 'btn-disabled' : btnHome}">
         <i class="fa fa-home fa-navbar"></i>
         Home
      </a>
      <a href="#/second" class="btn btn-navbar btn-icon-only">
         Next 
         <i class="" ng-class="{'fa fa-arrow-right fa-navbar':true, 'btn-disabled' : btnNext}"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using $rootScope.$broadcast but nobody is listening, you need to have a scope watcher in your controller that actually controls the buttons:

```
 //####################### - Next Back Controller ########################
app.controller("nextBackController",
    function($scope, nxtBackClick, bottomButtonWatcher){

        $scope.btnHome = bottomButtonWatcher.btnHome;
        $scope.btnNext = bottomButtonWatcher.btnNext;
        $scope.btnBack = bottomButtonWatcher.btnBack;

        $scope.handleClick = function(btn) {
            nxtBackClick.broadcast(btn);
        };

        $scope.$watch('bottomBtnClick', function(buttonVal){
             $scope[buttonVal] = true;
        });
    }

);
```

Comment: The bottomBtnClick broadcast event is monitored in another controler (since each controller will do something different when "next" is clicked).  I just want to monitor the bottomButtonWatcher.btnNext variable and change the $scope.btnNext variable appropriately

Comment: I guess my point was that you don't need to have a service that just maintains those variables if you just implement a watcher in the controller for your bottom buttons. Make sense?